# Why does this work when plugged into GFCI and blow a house circuit breaker when plugged into standard outlet

Tags: electrical, gfci, circuit

I connected two 14 AWG 3 Conductor 3-Prong Power Cords to a 15 amp 125 V GFCI outlet. I tied all three hot wires together, all three neutral wires together, and all three ground wires together. I also connected the ground wires to the metal box holding the GFCI outlet using a pigtail.

[image]

My goal was to have this function so that if either or both power cords are hot then the outlet will be hot. It worked as I expected when I plugged the power cords into a GFCI outlet. However, when I plugged the power cords into a standard outlet it blows the house circuit breaker that the standard outlet is connected to.

For my application that’s not a problem since I’ll be plugging into a GFCI outlet, however it concerns me that it doesn't work on a standard outlet. Should I be concerned?

Comment: You should be concerned that you have built a suicide cord.

Comment: Well done on coming with a whole new variation on a Suicide Cord! In all likelihood, your "standard outlet" is actually wired up to a Multi-Wire-Branch-Circuit such that the hot wire on each half comes from a different 'phase' - so by plugging you suicide device in you're creating a dead short across a 240V line. A GFCI is only fed by a single 'phase' so you don't see the same problem there.

Comment: Is it really a standard(single power) outlet or is it on a MWBC circuit(with two breakers)?  Turn off the breaker for the standard outlet and see what wires are connected to it.

Comment: Try searching online for a "sever rack transfer switch." That'll lead you to a ready-made device which contains the necessary safety and logic circuits to reach your goal in a safe way.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this device?  If you describe it we can possibly help you rethink this in a way that will accomplish something useful without being so dangerous.

Comment: I have a thermostat that is connected to an outlet. When the thermostat kicks in the outlet becomes live. I connect this to a fan. It works great. Now however I have a second thermostat also connected to an outlet. I would like to connect both thermostats to the same fan so that if either or both outlets gets triggered by its thermostat the one fan comes on.

Comment: I should also mention the thermostats are in different areas (separated by a few feet). The temperature does vary between the two areas but the fan services both areas.

Comment: Both thermostats will be set to kick in if the temperature drops below 40 degrees in either area.

Comment: A) put your use case (in the 3 comments above) into your question so more people will see it. B) investigate smart outlets and a couple of smart temperature sensors. Those are designed to be able to do what you're after without killing you. Some of the basic ones don't need to phone home and you can set them up with a simple app on your phone.

Comment: @John It seems like you haven't thought about what happens when both areas drop to below 40 degrees. Both outlets will be on

Comment: Joe -sorry, I thought I made it clear. The fan serves both areas. Therefore when either drops below 40 degrees I want the fan on. I also want it on if both areas drop below 40 degrees. If you know what an "OR" gate is that's how this should work. If one or both areas drop below 40 degrees the fan starts. The only time the fan is off is if neither area is below 40 degrees.

Comment: FreeMan - Thanks. When I first started this project I looked at smart outlets & temperature sensors. I did actually find an HVAC system that did this (and a lot of other things) but it was just under $1,000. I'll research more smart outlets & smart temperature sensors. I'm sure there's something simple and cheap out there. I just need to find it.

Comment: @John Are the outlets on the same circuit? If so, I suppose that would work as an OR gate but not very safe, as people have mentioned. If they're on different circuits / phases, then you are just asking for trouble

Comment: @Joe I agree, it's too dangerous. I know it could be built with relays but it seems like that's something that is simple enough that there should be something off the shelf that would function that way and be safe. I just can't find it so far. That is a device that would take two electrical lines as input and have a outlet that is live if either or both input lines are live.

Answer (score 12):

You should learn what a Multiwire Branch Circuit is, as that's probably what you plugged your suicide cord in to.

Such circuits are common in Kitchens, particularly, and have the halves of the outlet fed from opposite phase hots - 120V each hot to neutral/ground, but 240V hot to hot, so when you plug in your suicide cord (special edition with outlet in the middle) you are shorting across 240V.

If either plug on your suicide cord is unplugged, while the other is plugged in, it has exposed live contacts, and is a violation of both codes and common sense. Please disassemble this thing before you kill someone (that might not be you; which would make it  a *negligent homicide cord* at least.)

*You can do this, from a single circuit, by hardwiring methods. NOT by cord and plug. The difference being that nobody can unplug a hardwired cable to expose live contacts. You can also do it by using a transfer switch, which could be cord and plug connected.*